# Automated Email content editing before forwarding

Tags: email

I wanted to know if there is any service which allows auto-editing of email content before forwarding it.

For example, suppose I receive a daily e-mail with a report from our database tool, which includes at the end:

```
For any question please contact support@tool.example.
Best regards,
Tool Team
```

Now, suppose I auto-forward these reports to some employees in my company, but I would like them to receive the report without these last 3 lines, or, alternatively, to replace them with:

```
For any question please contact myname@company.example.
Best regards,
My Name
```

I can do it manually of course, but I want the forwarding process to stay automated.

Is there a service which offers this feature? Even an online email service which includes a similar feature, it doesn't have to be my company's email address.

Thanks!